Should the runcmd under user-data section or is it a top level key?
I'm working on a cloud-config autoinstall YAML to install Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm encountering some unexpected behaviors. I've noticed that placing write-files and runcmd as top-level keys doesn't seem to work for me. However, when I move them under the user-data section, write-files does work, but the defer: true option isn't honored. Additionally, runcmd isn't executing as expected. To work around the defer: true issue, I tried manually invoking cc_write_files_deferred through cloud-init under runcmd, but that hasn't worked either. Could someone with expertise in cloud-config help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  apt:
  identity:
  kernel:
  keyboard:
  timezone: 
  locale: 
  network:
  source:
  ssh:
  late-commands:
  user-data:
    write_files:
    - path: /etc/sudoers
      content: |
        test ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
      append: true
    - path: /home/test/.profile
      content: |
        if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
              . "$HOME/.bashrc"
        fi
        if [ -e /home/test/.firstboot_success ]
        then
          sudo sed -i "s/===== STEM WILL REBOOT ITSELF UPON SUCCESS ==========/============ WELCOME ============/g" /etc/update-motd.d/motd
        fi
      append: true
      permissions: '0755'
      defer: true
    runcmd:
      - [ cloud-init, single, --name, cc_write_files_deferred, --frequency, always, --report ]
    output:
      all: '/run/install-output.log'

